# asp.net mvc 5 GetUser from ActiveContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

We have a asp.net mvc 5 web application with asp.net identity 2. In the active context i get the actual user from "HttpContext.User.Identity.Name".

Now a external service must get the information about the user which is actually logged in over a HTTPGet Request.

I thought i can request the username about the same approach. But the user is always string.empty. I think this is because the follwing post is not in the same httpcontext?!?!

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SupporterIdentity()
    {          
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.Name == string.Empty || HttpContext.User.Identity.Name == null)
        {
            return Json(new { success = "false", msg = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ;
        }

        var appUser = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Result;

        AppAuthentication oa = new AppAuthentication();
        oa.Identity = new AppIdentity();

        oa.Identity.id = appUser.Id.ToString();
        oa.Identity.name = appUser.UserName;
        oa.Identity.role = MemberDataIdentityModel.UserRole.ToString(); ;           

        return Json(oa, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

How can i get the active user from the right context?? What is the right approach?

Comment: Try this: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name

Comment: No sorry the value is string.empty, my opinion is that the get method dont know which is the associated httpcontext. But how can i achieve this? Is there the possibity to read the User Data from an authentication Cookie?

Comment: HttpContext contains information about the current HttpRequest what do you mean by request not being in the same HttpContext? Does this code snippet reside inside your external service that your server logic invokes after user does request to your application?

Or does the UserManager do the call to the external service you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if external process is doing GET request, should this request be authenticated in the first place?

If I login to your system, I get a cookie with authentication details. This is my cookie and my login. Some other process may call GET on your `/SupporterIdentity` but that request does not come with the same cookie as I have and that request does not come authenticated. So for that process there is no user logged-in, so you are correctly getting `String.Empty` instead of a username.

Just remove `[AllowAnonymous]` from that action and try - you should get a login page for that process GET request.

Another thing - you talk about the logged-in user as if there should never be 2 users logged-in at the same time. But there could be many users logged-in. So which username that GET request should return?